# Implement a squared, colored and round-edged button in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, button, styles, user-experience

I am trying to design an Android app with a button driven user interface. This means that there are a few buttons, with different colors and icons, and each one does its task.

I've tried to implement this using standard, and custom styled buttons, but they did not have a nice UI, and they do not support icons inside them.

I tried with fabs but fabs are not meant for this purpose, and I'm looking for something slightly rounded, more like that:

[image: colored and rounded buttons]

That would be perfect because the buttons are colored, squared with rounded edges, they contain an icon and they have a label underneath them.

Any advice / sample to replicate this same kind of view?
For the color, you just have to pick from the palette a light and dark variant.
Putting the text label under the button is pretty straightforward, but I have no idea about how to code in XML something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would do it like this

Here is the button layout. ic_baseline_folder_24 is a vector asset generated using Android Studio

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/folder_button"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_image_button"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_folder_24" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Folders"
    android:textColor="#CCC" />

</LinearLayout>
```

bg_image_button.xml is defined like this. It can be extended to support different states:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <shape >
      <solid android:color="#7B0800"/>
      <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Finally, set the click action handler:

```
val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
binding.folderButton.setOnClickListener {
  // do something
}
```

It results like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to programmatically change the background color of the image view?

Comment: @AndreaCioccarelli Changing the background color here requires that you change the background color of your drawable, in this case, bg_image_button.xml. This is a few lines of code that you need to do each time you want to make this happen. And let's not forget that you need to create so many of these XMLs to have different colors in your menu. Going with the solution I provided and CardView is in that case a better solution since you can change background color with one simple line: cardView.setBackgroundColor(color); And it won't affect other menu items.

Comment: The background color can be changed programmatically using `setBackgroundResource(int resId)` with different background xml resources. If the image view required different states like disabled, clicked, activated, I believe it's easier. If no states variation required, SlothCoding's solution works well too.

Comment: Thank you to both. This has been super useful and straightforward :)

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is this. I used CardView to create a button with rounded edges. CardView is great and easy to use and you can later easily change anything you want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">
        
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="52dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

With this code you get this:

[image]

Now just in your code type:

```
LinearLayout btn_settings = findViewById(R.id.btn_settings);
btn_settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               //do something
           }
       });
```

Now just inside onClick enter your code to handle clicks on the button. Make more layouts like this and add them to whatever view you want. GridView, RecylcerView, etc to generate more buttons like in your photo and handle clicks for each of them.